# Pythonとelectronを使用したGUIアプリケーションの作成について

Tags: javascript, python, ubuntu, electron

環境
ubuntu16.04 LTS
python 2.712 , python 3.5.2
electron 1.8.2

Pythonを用いたGUIアプリの開発をしてみたいなと思い、Electronを使用した開発を試みるべく、以下のページを参考にしました。

https://qiita.com/yoshizaki_kkgk/items/da9711c26e71522ad289

上記のページのコードをそのままコピーペーストし、ページ内に記載のあるモジュールのインストールもしたのですが、electronのコマンドを実行しても、Terminalでもエラーメッセージ等表示されず、electronも起動しませんでした。
main.js自体がうまく働いてないのか、Pythonのプログラム自体が働いてないのかわかりません。
しかし、main.js内のコンソールへの文字の出力が行われてないので、main.js自体に問題があるのかもしれないのですが、完全にコピーペーストなので考えづらく、まったく解決方法が思いつかない状態です。
electron自体はJavaScriptのみでの簡単なアプリケーションの作成では機能したので問題ないかと思われます。

```js
//main.js    
// Electron側の初期設定
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
let mainWindow;

// アプリを閉じた時にquit
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  app.quit();
});

// アプリ起動後の処理
app.on('ready', function() {
  var subpy = require('child_process').spawn('python',['./hello.py']);
  var rq = require('request-promise');
  var mainAddr = 'http://localhost:5000';

  var openWindow = function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 300 });
    mainWindow.loadURL(mainAddr);

    // 終了処理
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
      mainWindow = null;
      subpy.kill('SIGINT');
    });
  };

  var startUp = function() {
    rq(mainAddr)
      .then(function(htmlString) {
        console.log('server started');
        openWindow();
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        startUp();
      });
  };

  startUp();
});



#hello.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import time
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def hello():
    return "Hello World!<br>This is powered by Python backend."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('on hello')
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

ページ内に記載のあるコマンドを少し変えました。下記に記します。

```sh
$ npm install request -g
$ npm install request-promise -g
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "PythonApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "request-promise": "*",
    "electron-prebuilt": "*"
  }
}
```

このようなトラブルの解決方法を知っている方がいましたらおねがいします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/114729

Comment: electronが起動しないのではなく、electronが起動してはいるが、ウィンドウもなにも生成されず、electron .を実行してもカーソルが点滅するだけでなにも起こっていないという感じです。htbさんがコメントに書いていますが、teratailでも同じ質問をさせていただいております。コード等はお手数ですがそちらの方からコピーペーストしていただけたら幸いです。

Comment: PythonはFlaskのウェブサーバーですけれども、結局HTTPで通信するのだし、わざわざチャイルドプロセスで起動しなくても良いのでは？

Comment: Kenji Noguchiさん。そのとおりなのですが、なぜこのプログラムが正常に作動しないのか気になっていたんですよね。main.jsもpackage.jsonもhello.pyも完全にコピペなのになにがダメなのかわからないんですよね。Pythonはともかく、Javascriptはあまり明るくないのでmain.jsになんらかの問題があるのかどうかも恥ずかしながらわからないんですよね。

Answer (score 1):

既に解決していらっしゃるかもしれませんが一応。

```
var subpy = require('child_process').spawn('python',['./hello.py']);
```

となっていますが、環境変数にpythonのパスは通っていますか？
ここの spawn('python',['./hello.py']); は

```
python hello.py
```

というコマンドを打っていることと同義なので、パスが設定されていないのであればここが原因である可能性が高いです。

Comment: コメント遅くなって申し訳ありません。試してみたところ、解決しました。